# UI Router nested state parameters are same as father state parameters

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a routing like this:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('Lorem', {
        url: '/Lorem',
        params: { type: 'A'},
        templateUrl: 'views/lorem.html',
        controller: 'loremCtrl as ctrl'
    })
    .state('Lorem.son', {
        url: '/son',
        params: { position: 'X'},
        templateUrl: 'views/lorem.son.html',
        controller: 'loremSonCtrl as ctrl'
    })
```

When I go to `/Lorem/son` route, my `$stateParams` is set with the father `Lorem` state params. 
Why does this happen? 
I just want read `Lorem.son` state params.

Can someone help me?

Comment: How are you setting the params for the state Lorem.son when you go to /Lorem/son?

Comment: I have set nothing. I just set the default parameters in routing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The controller of state `Lorem.son` is not being executed at all that's why you don't see the value of `position`. And that's because you are not using `ui-view` directive.

You need to nest the views by adding following in your `views/lorem.html`:

```
<div ui-view />
```

For more details check [documentation of ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing).

Check this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/aLPJj9WzdOInt5bzqPii?p=preview) for demo.

Comment: the structure of views that i have is correct, is like how you wrote

Comment: I have added the demo in the answer, check that.

Comment: I've added a 'alert(JSON.stringify($stateParams))' in Lorem.son controller and i see {"type":"A","position":"X"}. Can you explain me why i see also father parameters?

Comment: Because the state `Lorem.son` in being inherited from `Lorem`.